# get a php web page to refresh if a session variable is set

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a web page set up and I'm using PHP, JavaScript, AJAX and jQuery in that page, obviously along with HTML and CSS.  I'm using jQuery in the page to hide/show some of the page content dependent on selections made by the user.  The page also has a couple of popups that also enable the user to do things with the content in the page (doing things in the database, etc).

Everything works fine apart from when the user does things with one of the popups.  When that popup is used, the page doesn’t load properly afterwards.  I know the problem has something to do with jQuery, because the page stops loading at the point in the code where the jQuery code actually starts.

Anyway, I know that I can press F5 when the problem discussed above occurs, because when I do that the page re-loads normally (without any sign on previous failure).  Therefore, it seems like I need to find a way of refreshing the page automatically in my code, when necessary.

I’ve already set up a session variable that gets set when the popup code is run (as shown below).

```
$_SESSION[‘appointment_clipboard_updated’] = 1;
```

I also need to set up code in the page that has the problem, which checks if that session variable is set.  If the session variable is set, I need code that actually refreshes the page in the same way as would happen if F5 was pressed.

I have tried the following as a way of refreshing in the problematic page, which doesn’t work:

```
if (isset( $_SESSION[‘appointment_clipboard_updated’]) && $_SESSION[‘appointment_clipboard_updated’] == 1)
{
    unset($_SESSION[‘appointment_clipboard_updated’]);

    header(‘Location:  /index.php’);
    exit();
}
```

I’ve also tried changing the header call in the code above as follows, but that also didn’t work:

```
header(‘Refresh: 1;  /index.php’);
```

Therefore, if anyone has a workable solution for this problem, please let me know.  Big thanks in advance to anyone who offers any help.

I have already spent time searching the web for a solution and I've also had a good look at what's available on this website, but so far I've not found anything that resolves my problem.

the following is jQuery from the header in my page:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function()
    {
        if ($(this).attr("value")=="s-a-m")
        {
            if ($('#s-a-m_checkbox').is(':checked'))
            {
                $('#s-a-m_textarea').show();
                $('#s-a-m_components').show();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#s-a-m_textarea').hide();
                $('#s-a-m_components').hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

the bit above hides or shows page components as necessary.  I'll show the code for actually hiding stuff in my HTML further down.

the bit below is what I use to keep everything hidden until the page finishes loading:

```
$(window).load(function()
{
    $('#hide-until-loaded').fadeIn(50);
);
```

the next bit is what I use to keep everything hidden until the loading completes.  This is simnply a div and all the html/php code that's used to generate page content is kept within it:

```
<div id='hide-until-loaded' style='display: none;'>
```

There is also a closer for that div near the bottom of the file, which I haven't shown here.

there are also two other divs that hide specific sections of code (a textarea, plus a few other editable page components).  these are both within the 'keep hidden until loaded' div shown above.  The divs for hiding/showing showing page components are shown below, although as before I haven't shown there closers

```
<div id='s-a-m_textarea'>

<div id='s-a-m_components'>
```

Also, everything worked fine with the jQuery, before I started trying yo use the popup.  Also, the popup has been in the page for 2 or 3 years and that always worked without problem, until I introduced the jQuery.  therefore, for some strange reason the two parts just cause problems for each other.

Finally, all I want to do is refresh the page, because I know it's problem solved when I can get that working.  I can see that by clicking F5 when the problem I'm trying to resolve occurs.

Comment: did you get any console log error to show?

Comment: Simple truth is that I don't know what a 'console log error' is, or how I would get it to show.  Do you want to give me more info on that?

Comment: you have to check for your apache error log and while u are debugging, at your browser, select the debugging tools , at chrome, firefox, safari, etc... and see if you have a javascript syntax error or what is going on. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: I just want to refresh the page, like I've explained above.  This is because that's all I need to do to resolve my problem.  As far as I'm concerned what you're suggesting is unnecessary, so I'm not going to spend time looking into it.  If you have suggestions that can help with actually refreshing the page, please let me know, otherwise there's no point in me continuing to communicate with you over this.

Comment: Also, I'm not using apache.  The site runs in IIS on a Windows Server

Comment: I would advise using FireFox with FireBug. It's console, which logs browser side errors, has a "Persist" option that is very helpful in issues of this nature. Normally, the console is refreshed along with the page, so the error is lost. It would help us a lot to include the JQuery you're using, we may be able to identify the issue in it.

Comment: I'm using jQuery to do 2 things. To begin with I needed to hide/show page components according to what the user was doing, so I have code set up to cover that. Also, after setting up what's described above, I found that the page components that were meant to be hidden appeared when the page first opened.  I then also set up additional jQuery that keeps everything hidden until the page finishes loading and that cleared the issue with hidden stuff appearing when it shouldn’t do. I will post up the code for the different bits of jQuery after I’ve put this up. Might take a few minutes to sort out.

Comment: OK, I've put the jQuery with comments above (at the bottom of my original post).

Comment: It would really help you to diagnose the problem with the javascript that's running if you knew if there were any errors in the console. The console is in simple terms the browser's javascript environment's equivalent of the IIS error log. In Chrome, press F12 to open developer tools, and go to the Console tab. If there is anything amiss with the syntax of the jQuery/JS, you'll see errors here.

Comment: If you're trying to change the page location using PHP, it's possible that you're calling `header('Location:' ... )` too late. You can't send any headers if content has already been output to the page. If you can check your PHP log try looking for something along the lines of that.

Comment: mcon - I've tried putting the header() call right at the top of the home page and I still get exactly the same problem

Comment: Dan Abrey - I've tried what you've said in  Chrome with pressing F12 and going to the Console tab.  When I've got the browser set up like that, I've tried using the popup again that causes the problem.  the problem still occurs, but I see absolutely nothing in the console tab (completely empty??).

Comment: Eventually, I resolved this problem by myself through my own trial and error approach to sorting out the code.  Basically, there was also some AJAX that was being used in the page that was giving me the problem.  I therefore tried disabling that AJAX code and the problem with the page failing to load properly was cleared.  I then set up some alternative code to cover what the AJAX was previously doing.  That that has now been done and everything works perfectly in the page as a result.